# Finding a Key's Value from an object within an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, loops

I have tried many things to get this working correctly but I can't

Here is my problem:

I have an array of objects in javascript which looks something like this:

```
var myArrOfObjs = [];
var myObject1 = {};
myObject1.key = '1234';
myObject1.label = 'Richard Clifford';

myArrOfObjs.push( myObject1 );
```

and I need to do something like:

```
if( !containsObject( myObject1, myArrOfOjbs ) ){
    // Do stuff
}
```

I need the `containsObject` function to check for key values within the found object (if any), so if `containsObject( myObject1, myArrOfOjbs )` finds the object, I need to check to see if the key of that is the same as the one I am currently trying to push.

The reason I need it to check the keys is because I have tried this function which I found else where on StackOverflow, but it isn't quite working.

```
function containsObject(obj, list) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i] == obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

It still pushes the object to the array even when it already contains the object.

Please let me know if you need anything clearing up, I realise that it isn't the easiest post to read/understand.

Thanks!

Comment: This containsObject method should work. There is probably a problem with the calling code. Could you show it (make an autonomous reduced code displaying the problem if possible) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the equality test to compare the keys:

```
function containsObject(obj, list) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].key === obj.key) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Shows how little I know about javascript. I've only just start learning it. So thanks a lot! much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have got this function that gets added to the prototype-chain of the Array-Object, so you can just call `list.hasObject(obj)`.

```
Array.prototype.hasObject = (
  !Array.indexOf ? function (o)
  {
    var l = this.length + 1;
    while (l -= 1)
    {
        if (this[l - 1] === o)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  } : function (o)
  {
    return (this.indexOf(o) !== -1);
  }
);
```

small fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/NE9kx/

Comment: Good answer, but I have gone with the above one. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not the answer you're looking for, but I wonder why don't use an Object instead of an Array, if you have a key:

```
var objectList = {};

var myObject { key : '1234', label : 'Richard Clifford' };

objectList[myObject.key] = myObject;
```

So if you want to iterate:

```
for (var key in objectList) {
    if (objectList.hasOwnProperty(key)
        alert(key);
}
```

If you want to access to the object with a key given you have just to:

```
alert(objectList['1234'].label);
```

Comment: The reason why is due to the third-party software which I am writing an extension for, it uses an array of objects. Thanks for the suggestion for future reference I will use objects :)